# Rshiny timevis snap option (vis.js)

Tags: r, shiny, vis.js

Having trouble passing the snap option to vis.js through Rshiny. When I attempt to pass the snap option, I wind up with wonky behavior when trying to move calendar items.

I assign the day like so:

```
today <- as.character(Sys.Date())
```

and then pass the option with:

```
snap = list(date = today, scale = 'minute', step= 15)
```

My goal is to snap my calendar items to 15 minute increments, but the default for my view seems to be 30 minute blocks.

```
if (interactive()) {
  library(shiny)
  
  starthour <- 8
  today <- as.character(Sys.Date())
  todayzero <- paste(today,"00:00:00")
  todayAM <- paste(today,"07:00:00")
  todayPM <- paste(today, "18:00:00")
  
  items <- data.frame(
    category = c("Room","IceBreaker","Activity","Break"),
    group=c(1,2,3,4),
    className   = c ("red_point", "blue_point", "green_point","purple_point"),
    content = c("Big Room","Introductions","Red Rover","Lunch"),
    length = c(480,60,120,90)
  )
  
  groups <- data.frame(id= items$group, content = items$category)
  
  data <- items %>% mutate(id = 1:4,
                           start = as.POSIXct(todayzero) + hours(starthour),
                           end   = as.POSIXct(todayzero) + hours(starthour) + minutes(items$length)
  )
  
  ui <- fluidPage(
    tags$head(
      tags$style(HTML("
                        .red_point  { border-color: red; border-width: 2px;   }
                        .blue_point { border-color: blue; border-width: 2px;  }
                        .green_point  { border-color: green; border-width: 2px;   }
                        .purple_point { border-color: purple; border-width: 2px;  }
                        "))),
    timevisOutput("appts"),
    div("Selected items:", textOutput("selected", inline = TRUE)),
    div("Visible window:", textOutput("window", inline = TRUE)),
    tableOutput("table")
  )
  
  server <- function(input, output) {
    output$appts <- renderTimevis(
      timevis(
        data = data,
        groups = groups,
        fit = TRUE,
        options = list(editable = TRUE, 
                       multiselect = TRUE, 
                       align = "center", 
                       stack = TRUE,
                       start = todayAM,
                       end = todayPM,
                       showCurrentTime = FALSE,
                       showMajorLabels=FALSE, 
                       snap = list(date = today, scale = 'minute', step= 15))
        
      )
    )
    
    output$selected <- renderText(
      paste(input$appts_selected, collapse = " ")
    )
    
    output$window <- renderText(
      paste(input$appts_window[1], "to", input$appts_window[2])
    )
    
    output$table <- renderTable(
      input$appts_data
    )
  }
  shinyApp(ui, server)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use the option `timeAxis`, not the `snap` option:

```
library(shiny)
library(timevis)

data <- data.frame(
  id = 1:3,
  start = c("2015-04-04", "2015-04-04 02:00:00", "2015-04-04 05:00:00"),
  end = c("2015-04-04 06:00:00", NA, NA),
  content = c("<h2>Vacation!!!</h2>", "Acupuncture", "Massage"),
  style = c("color: red;", NA, NA)
)

ui <- fluidPage(
  timevisOutput("appts")
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  output$appts <- renderTimevis(
    timevis(
      data,
      options = list(
        editable = TRUE, 
        multiselect = TRUE, 
        align = "center",
        timeAxis = list(scale = "minute", step = 15)
      )
    )
  )
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

## EDIT

I misunderstood the question. Indeed, you need the `snap` option. This option must be a JavaScript function. Here is the app:

```
library(shiny)
library(timevis)

data <- data.frame(
  id = 1:3,
  start = c("2015-04-04", "2015-04-04 02:00:00", "2015-04-04 05:00:00"),
  end = c("2015-04-04 06:00:00", NA, NA),
  content = c("<h2>Vacation!!!</h2>", "Acupuncture", "Massage"),
  style = c("color: red;", NA, NA)
)

ui <- fluidPage(
  timevisOutput("appts")
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  output$appts <- renderTimevis(
    timevis(
      data,
      options = list(
        editable = TRUE, 
        multiselect = TRUE, 
        align = "center",
        timeAxis = list(scale = "hour", step = 1),
        snap = JS(
          c(
            "function(date, scale, step){",
            "  var quarter = 15 * 60 * 1000;",
            "  return Math.round(date / quarter) * quarter;",
            "}"
          )
        )
      )
    )
  )
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image]

Comment: I had actually tried that as well. But it made the displayed axis have increments every 15 minutes and visually unappealing.  I still want the time axis to be incremented by hours.

Comment: @Steve Sorry I don't understand. If you want increments every hour, what do you mean by "15 minutes increments" in your question?

Comment: I would like the axis to visually be displayed as every hour. But when I click on an item to move it, I would like for it to "snap" to the timeline in 15 minute increments.  Currently if you move an item, it snaps to 30 minute increments.   So you can only move it to the hour, or half hour.

Comment: You may have to restrict your example to only show an 8 hour block of time like in my example to get the same result? I'm not at my computer, so I can't verify that.

Comment: @Steve I think I see what you mean now. Please take a look at my edit.

Comment: Yes!  I would have never figured that out!  Thank you again.